# Node js server doesn't display images in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a site in the frontend and decided to add the backend to it (to fetch data and modify it in general). The backend provides data to the frontend but there is a problem with images and I don't know why. data.js provides _id, URL, title, flavor, category, region, variety, and description, but no image (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)).

I tried to search for the answer and didn't find any which works for me, unfortunately. I also use my own configuration of webpack5 for the frontend.

Here is link to the repo: [link to the repo](https://github.com/markot999/image-problem-webpack-react-node).

Below I present you all the important information:

Node v16.13.2

My file structure:

```
mainFolder
 - backend
    -- data.js
    -- server.js
 - frontend
    -- config
      --- webpack.common.js
      --- webpack.config.js
      --- webpack.dev.js
      --- webpack.prod.js
    -- public
      --- folder
        ---- pic.jpg
    -- src
      --- (...)
        ---- frontend.js
    -- (...)
    -- package.json (in frontend folder)
 - package.json (in root folder)
```

package.json (in root folder):

```
{
  "name": ...,
  "type": "module",
  "version": ...,
  "description": ...,
  "author": ...,
  "license": ...,
  "main": ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec node --experimental-modules backend/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

package.json (in frontend folder):

```
{
  "name": ...,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
  "version": ...,
  "description": ...,
  "author": ...,
  "license": ...,
  "main": ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.config.js --env env=dev",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.config.js --env env=prod"
  },
  "devDependencies": {...},
  "dependencies": {...}
}
```

server.js:

```
import express from 'express'
import data from './data.js'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data.products)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('server is ready')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}}`)
})
```

data.js:

```
const data = {
  products: [
    {
      _id: 1,
      url: 'url',
      title: 'title',
      flavor: 'flavor',
      category: 'category',
      image: '/images/folder/pic.jpg',
      region: 'region',
      variety: 'variety',
      description:'description',
    },
    {...},
  ],
}

export default data
```

frontend.js:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Frontend = ({ match }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')
      setProducts(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const list = products.map((product) => (
    <li key={product._id}>
      <Link to={`${match.url}/${product.url}`}>
        <img
          src={product.image}
          alt={product.url}
        />
        <div>
          <h2>{product.title}</h2>
          <p>{product.flavor}</p>
          <button>View more</button>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{list}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Frontend
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.js'),

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash:6].js',
    clean: true,
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|mp4)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|pdf)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline',
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: '...',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/template/template.html'),
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './public/favicon.ico'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    }),
  ],
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = ({ env }) => {
  const envConfig = require(`./webpack.${env}.js`)

  return merge(commonConfig, envConfig)
}
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:8000',
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './dist'),
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              plugins: [require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './.env.development'),
    }),
    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:6].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(s[ac]|c)ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash:6].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './.env.production'),
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), '...'],
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'runtime',
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Try sharing your project in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy here is the code. I put it on GitHub [link to the repo](https://github.com/markot999/image-problem-webpack-react-node). I resign from codesandbox because it can be a problem with my custom webpack. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are not using static files in your express app. You should add the static files to your express app and serve the pictures on your back-end server.

Basically you can have a look at this [document](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Also if you prefer videos you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUQAt1xfUWI&ab_channel=DevSprout).

First of all, your backend file should be like;

```
backend
  -server.js
  -data.js
  -public
    --images
       ---coffee
         ----pic.jpg
```

Here is server.js file:

```js
import express from 'express'
import data from './data.js'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data.products)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('server is ready')
})

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.use('/static',express.static('public'))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}}`)
})

// go to 'http://localhost:8000/images/coffee/pic.jpg' it will work
```

Comment: if I add lines like you suggested (src path is `'/static/images/folder/pic.jpg'` or `'/images/folder/pic.jpg'` depends of what is in server.js file): `import path from 'path' | const __dirname = path.resolve() | app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))` or `app.use('/static', express.static('public'))` to the server.js file it doesn't change anything. There still is an error :(

Comment: Yes it won't work because your public folder in the frontend folder (I missed this part :c). You should move it to your backend folder. You should also use `app.use('static',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))` and  `/static/images/pic.jpg`

Comment: I moved the public folder from the frontend folder to the backend folder. I also add `app.use('static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))`, also tried `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))`, also I change src path to `/static/images/pic.jpg` and nothing, still have `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` - of curse only for the image. Did you download my repo and does your solution work for you? What is more location of the public folder does really matter if I use a proxy for my frontend?

Comment: I downloaded your repo and edited my post. You can change your server.js file and `http://localhost:8000/images/coffee/pic.jpg` will work

Comment: Yes, now it's working. Thank you :) Do you maybe have an idea how to put it on (for example) netlify? Because working on it locally is fine but also it would be good to show it globaly.

Comment: Glad I could help :) unfortunately I haven't used netlify before :c

Answer (score 0):

Just to add real life simple example to make it more easier
on your server.js/ add this middleware, public folder can be named whatever your folder that hold static files for me it "assets"

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```